# If $M_1$ and $M_2$ are distinct maximal ideals of, then $R/M_1 \otimes _R R/M_2=0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

> $R$ is a commutative ring with $1$ and $M_1,M_2$ are distinct maximal ideals of $R$. Then $R/M_1 \otimes _R R/M_2=0.$

Consider $f:R/M_1 \times R/M_2\to  R/M_1 \otimes _R R/M_2 $ defined by $f(r+M_1,s+M_2)=(r+M_1)\otimes (r+M_2)$

I can show this map is $R$-bilinear.  By the universal property of tensor products $f$ induces a homomorphism $\phi:R/M_1 \otimes _R R/M_2\to R/M_1\cap M_2=R/(1)=0$, but how can I show this map is an isomorphism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different strategy, for the particular case, is considering $r\in M_1$ such that $r\notin M_2$. Then every element of $R/M_2$ is of the form $rs+M_2$ and, for any $t\in R$, we have
$$
(t+M_1)\otimes(rs+M_2)=(rt+M_1)\otimes(s+M_2)=0
$$

Comment: As $s$ varies in $R$, how do we know any $m\in M_1$ can be expressed as $rs$?

Comment: @cap I didn't say that. Rather, that for any $x\in R$ there exists $s$ such that $x-rs\inM_2$, which follows from $M_1$ being maximal.

Answer (score 5):

This follows at once if you show that
$$R/I \otimes R/J \simeq R/(I+J)$$

Comment: (This proves the claim for comaximal ideals.)